# Type error for api function in react-query

Tags: reactjs, react-query

```
import {useMutation, useQueryClient} from 'react-query';
import axios from 'axios';

interface userInterface {
 email: string;
 password: string;
}


const loginUser = (user:userInterface) => {
   return axios.post('http://127.0.0.0/login',user);
};

export const useLoginApi = () => {
  interface BodyInterface {
     email: string;
     password: string;
  }

  interface ErrorInterface {
    status: string;
  }

  const {
    mutate: loginUserMutator,
    isError,
    error,
  } = useMutation<BodyInterface, ErrorInterface>(loginUser);

  return {
    loginUserMutator,
    isError,
    error,
  };
};
```

In here `loginUser` function showing as an error saying,

**No overload matches this call.The last overload gave the following error.Argument of type '() => Promise<AxiosResponse<any, any>>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MutationKey'.ts(2769).useMutation.d.ts(6, 25): The last overload is declared here.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useMutation` has 4 generics. If you only provide two, the other 2 will fall-back to the default generic. The 3rd one is for the `variables`, that explains the error. The first generic is for the return type of the mutation. You're not showing that it returns, and `BodyInterface` and `userInterface` are pretty much the same type ...

What you'd want is at least:

```
useMutation<User, ErrorInterface, BodyInterface >(loginUser);
```

- `User` - being what `loginUser` returns. Not sure what that is ...
- `BodyInterface` - being what you pass as variables to the mutation

but then again, the preferred way is to type the `loginUser` function and let the rest be inferred:

```
const loginUser = (user:userInterface): Promise<User> => {
   return axios.post('http://127.0.0.0/login',user);
};

useMutation(loginUser);
```

this will automatically infer input and output depending on `loginUser`. No, you cannot infer the Error type because there is no guarantee that this is really the error being returned, and rejected Promises cannot be typed. If you really want that, you need to pass the generics as shown above.